On net maui, how can I write a file in the Resources/Raw folder
I want to save a pdf in the Resources/Raw folder using File.WriteByteAsync(), but when trying to save it gives an error, it tries to save it to the file on disk C:
I believe this is not the correct way to write a file on net maui.

The app bundle is read-only at runtime.  See the docs on working with files

You may not have access to write to the folder.
If yes, You can try below code
    var FileName = "POF" ;
    var extension = ".pdf";
    var dir = string.Concat(_config.GetValue<string> 
               ("ConnectionStrings:SharedFilePath") + FileName + extension);
    using (var pdfFile = new FileStream(dir, FileMode.Create))
    {
        pdfFile.Write(pdfByte, 0, pdfByte.Length);
        pdfFile.Flush();
    }

